# how does wolfram alpha generate images with mathematical expressions?

Tags: image, image-generation, wolframalpha

I was just curious as to whether or not there's a library that converts mathematical expressions (non latex) to crisp looking images like wolfram alpha does.

For example, (n^2+5x+3)/n should output [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28n%5E2%2b5x%2b3%29/n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Begin [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML). But as it looks, it's not too simple to achieve this and in MathML, you can just show the formulas in the Browser, but not render it to images. Remember that the whole Mathematica software framework, which is extremely powerful and for sure has builtin functionality for such things, stands behind WolframAlpha.

**EDIT**: https://math.stackexchange.com/ does it too (MathML)., e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/convergence-of-npn-where-pn-sum-j-lceil-n-2-rceiln-1-pj-over-j) post. Ask them how they do it (on meta).

**EDIT again**: tadaaaa, just what you needed http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/mathml/asciimath.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using `(n^2 + 5 x + 3)/n // TraditionalForm // Rasterize` .

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question because it is LaTeX based, but there is a Javascript library called [jsmath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) that does such conversion.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284131/is-there-a-javascript-latex-equation-renderer) post explains it and other alternatives.