# Converting Tex to Image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, latex

Does anyone know how to convert a latex math expression into an image preferably without using an online tool but some javascript implementation. I've heard of MathJax but it doesn't have support for retrieving images. I know there tools out there that can do this but I don't want to query the site each time my page needs an image.

Comment: how exactly? My understanding of it is that it's used for drawing. The latex needs to be converted before I can draw it right?

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284131/is-there-a-javascript-latex-equation-renderer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284131/is-there-a-javascript-latex-equation-renderer)