# Django form input latex/equations?

Tags: django, forms, math, latex, equation

I am building a Q&A site for a university, and in order to ask and answer questions, it should be trivial to write equations and/or latex. Does anyone know of a good library that does this? It would be more than sufficient to use something like this (StackOverFlow) answering box, as everyone is familiar with it, and it's really easy to use.

**UPDATE**

I ended up using `django-pagedown` with `MathJax` and that's working pretty well. With some customization, I have pretty much SO's answering module with a `LaTeX` extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no Django way™ of displaying math equations. There's an HTML and JS way though. And you will be forced to do some of the work by hand.

As you can see in these SO questions from [2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116054/what-is-the-best-way-to-embed-latex-in-a-webpage) and [2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284131/is-there-a-javascript-latex-equation-renderer), the best way to embed latex equations in a webpage seems to be [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) (used by math.stackexchange.com), the replacement and evolution of [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsmath/) by the same developers. Read the MathJax [documentation](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/docsindex/) to get a hang of it.

The complex part is that you want the output panel to be dynamic. I never used math.stackexchange.com myself, but you could try to mimic what they do. Or just call MathJax after each keystroke if it's not too heavy.