# Rendering LaTeX between Dollar signs, like math.SE does

Tags: javascript, latex, substring, rendering

On the math SE site, one can render LaTeX by placing it between two Dollar signs, e.g. `$a \in X$`. It's also possible to type a literal Dollar sign by escaping with a backslash. What are the options available to me if I want to implement something similar? I'm guessing there must be a library that handles the difficult parts for me, but I haven't been able to find one! For example, in the string `Andrew Wiles proved that if $a^n+b^n=c^n$ for $a,b,c \in N$, then $n=1$`, only the things between the Dollar signs should be rendered as LaTeX.

Note: it's not so much the rendering part that I'm concerned with, as I know there's a multitude of libraries to do that, I just don't know how to actually extract what I need to render. Although if there is a library that both extracts and renders then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

**JsMath** does exactly what you want to do. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/authors/welcome.html)

This question was already [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284131/is-there-a-javascript-latex-equation-renderer).

Other alternatives are:

- [KaTex](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX)
- [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)