# Include LaTeX formulas in HTML files?

Tags: html, latex

I saw some sites include LaTeX formulas in their sites. How they do that?
Is there any HTML tag or maybe a SSI command to include LaTeX formulas?
I prefer there be a server-side command, not a client-side. Some clients don't have LaTeX compiler.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to embed LaTeX in a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116054/what-is-the-best-way-to-embed-latex-in-a-webpage)

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116054/what-is-the-best-way-to-embed-latex-in-a-webpage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is a possible solution.
It is a client-side solution (Javascript) which is compatible with LaTeX syntax.

I think [MathTran](http://www.mathtran.org/) provides an online outsourcing of your LaTeX files, which you can later embed in your HTML code (much in the way of the Google Chart Tools)

Depending on your server configuration (ie assuming you can install what you want), if the LaTeX files don't change often you could easily schedule a (say) LaTeX -> PNG render (lots of info the web on how to do it) and link the resulting PNG.

Last resort (but the simplest) if you have server limitations (say a shared host), you can just render the LaTeX to an image offline and upload the result.

Comment: Thanks, I found [codecogs](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/htmlequations.php) a good option for online clients.
It suits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) can do that job for you. Check out the website.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The point of your answer was already mentioned in the accepted answer quite some hours ago, so your answer is not bringing anything new.

Answer (score 0):

While **CodeCogs** ([updated hyperlink](https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php)) can be used to separately generate images that you can add later to your webpage using the tag `<img>`, a valid (and faster loading) alternative to **MathJax** is given by [**KaTeX**](https://katex.org/): I paste here a minimal example of implementation of this latter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Katex</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-zB1R0rpPzHqg7Kpt0Aljp8JPLqbXI3bhnPWROx27a9N0Ll6ZP/+DiW/UqRcLbRjq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-y23I5Q6l+B6vatafAwxRu/0oK/79VlbSz7Q9aiSZUvyWYIYsd+qj+o24G5ZU2zJz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Blah blah \(e^{i\pi}+1=0\) blah blah blah.</p>
\[e^{i\pi}+1=0\]
<p>Blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

All you need to do is to add one `link` and two `script` tags to your header, then you can write with LaTeX syntax inline math between the delimiters `\( \)` and displayed math between the delimiters `\[ \]`.