# How to embed latex formulas in html?

Tags: javascript, html, latex

I want to include some formulas in my HTML document, like this:

```
<h1>Embedded formula</h1>
<p>And here it goes!</p>
<p><span class="latex">x^n+y^n=z^n</span></p>
```

MathML seems a bit too complex for this task (and I already have a plenty of complex formulas in latex), so using latex seems to be a better route.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009075/include-latex-formulas-in-html-files) on stackoverflow, yet it is a bit outdated (many things changed in the last two years), and I would like for such html not to require connection to the Internet.

It seems that it is possible to implement jQuery plugin that will in some way interact with [texlive.js](https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js/) + [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) and perform the task in question, yet I would refrain from writing such a new library if some solution already exists.

Comment: Convert formulas by bash script and put into html png files instead.

Comment: If you think an existing question is outdated, you should try to have its answers improved, instead of intentionally posting a duplicate.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, MathJax is very slow javascript-based tool, I think, it's not good to use it in serious things; the only good thing is making png-images from formulae and pasting them into html. An ancient tool `latex2html` don't work in common cases (but sometimes it helps). Another tool `tex4mk` is even worse. Regrettably there's only one common way to convert latex into html: by hands!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to write LaTeX code in your HTML and have it rendered well, you probably want 
[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).  It requires Javascript, but the results are very good.  It's running on the [Mathematics StackExchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/) as well as lots of other sites.

Comment: MathJax seems to be the perfect answer; I wonder why I haven't found it earlier

Comment: @penartur You can try it out on the [demos page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/), too.  It's really quite impressive, although, since it just does math, not full fledged LaTeX, strange workarounds are sometimes necessary.  E.g., in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417935/equivalence-relation-using-tableaux/422719#422719) I had to use a whole bunch of nested arrays, where I think a cleaner solution would be available in raw LaTeX.

Comment: Hope it will be enough to satisfy my needs. The obvious problem is that it does not support latex packages (except for ones bundled with it such as **amsmath**) I believe; texlive.js+pdf.js combo, from the other hand, should support these.

Comment: as the side note, it is a weird coincidence that I asked this question to prepare a presentation for my thesis which also deals with the formula equivalence (though in form of "\phi \vdash \psi" AND "\psi \vdash \phi").

Comment: @penartur I haven't looked at texlive.js and pdf.js much, but the quick look I just had made it look more like those were still for compiling PDFs, no?

Comment: Yes, texlive.js is for compiling tex to pdf in javascript, and pdf.js is for rendering the resulting pdf in browser.

Comment: @penartur Doesn't that mean that you're not really embedding LaTeX formulae in HTML anymore, but PDF in HTML?

Comment: I mean it is possible to create a jQuery plugin that will replace all LaTeX formulas used in HTML with the `<canvas>` that will display PDF. The same thing **MathJax** does except that **MathJax** does not use `<canvas>` and PDF (and does not support LaTeX packages etc)

Answer (score 1):

You may use jsMath http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/welcome.html

Or, MathML that is a w3c standard, but it is currently not very well supported by browsers.