How to render LaTeX in Shiny for Python?
I'm trying to find if there is a way to render LaTeX formulas in Shiny for Python or any low-hanging fruit workaround for that.
Documentation doesn't have any LaTeX mentions, so looks like there's no dedicated functionality to support it.
Also double-checked different variations of Latex in their playground.
Tried this but didn't work:
from shiny.express import input, render, ui


@render.text
def txt():
    equation = r"$$\[3 \times 3+3-3 \]$$".strip()
    return equation


You can import Katex. I got here via https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540803/5599595. Running in shinylive
from shiny.express import ui
from shiny import render

with ui.tags.head():
    # Link KaTeX CSS
    ui.tags.link(
        rel="stylesheet",
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.0/dist/katex.min.css"
    ),
    ui.tags.script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.0/dist/katex.min.js"),
    ui.tags.script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.0/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js"),
    ui.tags.script("""
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            renderMathInElement(document.body);
        });
    """)

with ui.card():
    ui.p("Here's a quadratic formula: \\[x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\\]")
    ui.p("And an inline equation: \\(E = mc^2\\)")
    ui.p("\\[3 \\times 3+3-3 \\]")

Here's an alternative which can render the array running in shiny live:
from shiny.express import ui
from shiny import render

with ui.tags.head():
    ui.tags.link(
        rel="stylesheet",
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.0/dist/katex.min.css"
    ),
    ui.tags.script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.0/dist/katex.min.js"),
    ui.tags.script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.0/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js"),
    ui.tags.script("""
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            renderMathInElement(document.body, {
                    delimiters: [
                    {left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true},
                    {left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true},
                    {left: "$", right: "$", display: false},
                    {left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false}
                ]
            });
        });
    """)

with ui.card():
    ui.p("Here's a quadratic formula: $$x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$")
    ui.p("And an inline equation: $$E = mc^2$$")
    ui.p("And simple math $$3 \\times 3+3-3$$")

    # KaTeX tables https://www.redgregory.com/notion/2020/12/23/a-katex-table-cheatsheet-for-notion
    ui.p("Table 1 $$ \\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\\\ c & d \\end{array} $$")
    ui.p("""Table 2
    $$ \\begin{array} {|c|c|}
    \\hline
    A & B \\\\
    \\hline
    1 & 2 \\\\
    \\hline
    3 & 4 \\\\
    \\hline
    \\end{array} $$
    """.strip())


Looks encouraging, thank you!
One issue - not sure if it works for rendering tables.
I've tried a few examples using array from KaTeX docs, but doesn't work.
E.g. \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}. If you have any ideas - would appreciate it

I've added a different method which now renders the array. The need to escape all the slashes is pretty confusing!

You're da bomb! Thanks so much. I've slightly extended table examples if ok with you
